# How can I disable drag and drop on extension Redactor v10.1.1 for Yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, redactor, redactor.js

I'm using [yii2-redactor](https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-redactor). I'm trying to generally disable file drag and drop. Is there an option for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `dragUpload` didn't work for me. I found [here](https://imperavi.com/assets/pdf/redactor-documentation-10.pdf) a couple of options which worked for me. Example below.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(\yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::className(), [
  'clientOptions' => [
      'dragImageUpload' => false,
      'dragFileUpload' => false
  ]
])?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `clientOptions`. [Docs](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/upload/), For example

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(\yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::className(), [
  'clientOptions' => [
      'dragUpload' => false
  ]
])?>
```

According to latest [Docs](https://imperavi.com/assets/pdf/redactor-documentation-10.pdf), For example

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'body')->widget(\yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::className(), [
  'clientOptions' => [
      'dragImageUpload' => false,
      'dragFileUpload' => false
  ]
])?>
```